# Compare 3 elements in a single-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, compare

How can I check 3 elements of a single-dimensional array are equal to a specific value?

Background: I am trying to check for the winner of a game of tic-tac-toe (noughts and crosses). In other words check for any lines in a 3x3 grid flattened into a single dimensional array.

Here is the code I have tried:

Attempt 1:

```
switch ()
{
    case board[(6&3&0) || (7&4&1)]: case board[7&4&1]: case board[8&5&2]: case board[0&1&2]: case board[3&4&5]: case board[6&7&8]: case board[6&4&2]: case board[8&4&0]:
    System.out.println("Equal to x")
    break;
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
if (board[7] , board[4] , board[1] == 'X')
system.out.println("Equal");
```

Attempt 3:

```
if ( board[6&3&0] == 'X'  || board[7&4&1] == 'X' || board[8&5&2] == 'X' || board[0&1&2] == 'X' || board[3&4&5] == 'X' || board[6&7&8] == 'X' || board[6&4&2] == 'X' || board[8&4&0] == 'X') {
    System.out.println("Equal to x");
}else if
( board[6&3&0] == 'O'  || board[7&4&1] == 'O' || board[8&5&2] == 'O' || board[0&1&2] == 'O' || board[3&4&5] == 'O' || board[6&7&8] == 'X' || board[6&4&2] == 'O' || board[8&4&0] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("Equal to o!");
}
```

Comment: omg, what is this?

Comment: learn java syntax and then ask a question please. use 3d array. board[1][2][3] is valid but board[1&2&3] is not.

Comment: the criteria for the assignment is a single dimension array, that's why I'm stuck.

Comment: FlopCoder if any input is given for board[0] it automatically declares a win.

Comment: I also thought about turning the array into a list and comparing for 3 X's or O's but its my last resort, I know there is a simpler way to compare more than two elements

Comment: As beginner, you can solve the problem using 2D array. Its simple. Then you can modify you program to use 1D array. You just have to convert 2D accesses to 1D accesses using formula singleArrayIndexPosition = (row*3 + col); Rest of the program should work as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "playing-field" for tic-tac-toe looks like this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

With 0-8 being the indices in a `char[]` array:

```
marks = new char[9];
```

To check if we have three 'x' in a row:

```
'x' == marks[0] == marks[3] == marks[6] // a vertical row
'x' == marks[0] == marks[1] == marks[2] // a horizontal row
'x' == marks[0] == marks[4] == marks[8] // a diagonal row
```

This should get you started.

EDIT: And this will compile:

```
boolean win = marks[0] == 'x' && marks[3] == 'x' && marks[6] == 'x';
```

Comment: I tried a variety of combinations like:                          if ('X' == board[7] == board[4] == board[1])
   System.out.println("IT WORKS!"); to no avail.

Comment: my example `'x' == marks[0] == marks[3] == marks[6]` is NOT valid Java. I'll update my answer...

Comment: Ok I see, before i had used the normal & internally but you converted the whole statement into boolean so the && works instead! Perfect I had similar but was using the single &. awesome thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a 2-dimensional array for your board:

```
board = new char[3][3]
```

and you're wondering if you can map this to a single dimension.  The answer is yes.  Simply number the squares out in your head:

```
012
345
678
```

declare

```
board = new char[9]
```

and use those indices in your code.